# Using preg_replace in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, preg-replace

I have database data like `text [mydata] some text [otherdata] some more text` and I want to replace those `[mydata]` , `[otherdata]` with dynamic info such as category title for instance.

*So the result of my data would be like:*

```
text Category Title some text Category Desc some more text
```

instead of

```
text [mydata] some text [otherdata] some more text
```

I think that can be happen by `preg_replace` but not quite sure.

## code

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
  $notes = Notes::all();
  foreach($notes as $note){
     $descrip= $note->description;
  }

  $view->with('descrip', $descrip);
});
```

### More

So basically `$note->description` content is this data:

```
text [mydata] some text [otherdata] some more text
```

I want to replace those elements by data from `categories` table.

Any idea?

## Update

well i was digging and get code below (useing `str_replace`) however it has some issues,

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
            //getting categories and pull out the values i want to use as `[....]`
            $catC = Category::all();
            foreach($catC as $catD){
                $meta_title = $catD->title;
                $meta_desc = $catD->meta_description;
                $meta_tags = $catD->meta_tags;
            }
            //replace those categories values with element in database `[......]`
            $seotemplates = SeoTemplate::all();
            foreach($seotemplates as $seotemplate){
                $myCustom = str_replace_array('[cattitle]', [$meta_title, $meta_desc, $meta_tags], $seotemplate->categories_desc_template);
            }

            $view->with('myCustom', $myCustom);
        });
```

### Issues

1. I can only get `[cattitle]` but what about `[catmeta] & [cattags]`?
2. `$meta_title` will always return first value from categories table (for example if i'm visiting `HP` category page it return `ACER` as `[cattitle]` or any other category pages i visit. It's always ACER

## Update 2

I solved the issue 1 of my first update but still issue 2 remained, here is updated code

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
            //categories
            $catC = Category::all();
            $catD = [];
            foreach($catC as $catD){
                $catD = [
                    $cattitle = $catD->title,
                    $catmeta = $catD->meta_tags,
                    $catdesc = $catD->meta_description
                ];
            }
            $a1 = array("[cattitle]","[catmeta]","[catdesc]");

            $seotemplates = SeoTemplate::all();
            foreach($seotemplates as $seotemplate){
               $myCustom = str_replace($a1, $catD, $seotemplate->categories_desc_template);
             }

            $view->with('myCustom', $myCustom);
});
```

**Current issue:**

> 2. `$meta_title` will always return first value from categories table (for example if i'm visiting `HP` category page it return `ACER` as
>      `[cattitle]` or any other category pages i visit. It's always ACER

Comment: You don't need regex. You can use `str_replace`.

Comment: @user3783243 I've tried that It has some issue i'll update my question.

Comment: @user3783243 updated

Comment: Looks like there's some variable naming issue. Your `$catD` is not updated because it refers to the variable within the foreach scope. Define the outside variable as `$catE` and then inside the loop use `$catE = [
                    $cattitle = $catD->title, ... ]` ?

Comment: @hktang regarding to `$catE` result is the same as before i still get acer info instead of hp

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues with your code that I think will help with getting the solution that you are after.

First like mentioned by @hktang said in his comment you are duplicating your variables and then assigning it's value over and over again instead of adding to it. Try this:

```
$catE = [];
foreach($catC as $catD){
    $catE[] = [
        $cattitle = $catD->title,
        $catmeta = $catD->meta_tags,
        $catdesc = $catD->meta_description
    ];
}
```

Second you are also resetting the value of $myCustom with each loop of the for each. Try this:

```
$myCustom = []  
foreach($seotemplates as $seotemplate){
    $myCustom[] = str_replace($a1, $catE, $seotemplate->categories_desc_template);
}
```

This should result in you getting an array of seotemplates with the values replaced but I have not testing this.

Comment: regarding to `$catE` i'm getting `Array to string conversion` and i think `$myCustom` isn't right either should be equal to `[];` or `'';`

Comment: shouldn't i get `catE` in `str_replace` istead of `catD`?

Comment: and oh, `$catE` is already array if i make `$catE[] = [...]` will be array in array right? why would i make that?

Comment: anyway i'd tried your code here is the results:  `my DB` = `testing [catmeta] categories description --- [cattitle] -- [catdesc]`  the result i get `ffff` which is the value of `[catdesc]` it removed everything before and after `[catdesc]`